# Emscripten - C++ with pure html5 canvas support (not WebGL)

Tags: javascript, c++, canvas, emscripten

Is there any way of accessing canvas 2D context under C++ when using emscripten?
I'd like to be able to draw simple shapes/paths using canvas' api functions like `lineTo`, `fillRect`1d done, etc. (so basically use any of the functions listed [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp).

I will point out that I would prefer not to rely on SDL, but if it's the only reliable approach then is there a way to force it to compile to JavaScript so that the result won't use WebGL, but basic canvas api?

Or should I maybe do a simple mapping of the api functions following this suggestion: [Calling JavaScript From C/C++](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Interacting-with-code#calling-javascript-from-cc) ?

Until anyone shares a better solution I will most likely do the mapping and share it here as soon as I'm done with it.

Comment: Do your canvas set up in Javascript and do the mapping. Should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Or did you do the mapping?

Comment: Wish I could help but this was so long ago I can barely remember. I think I decided to do the mapping. Unfortunately the project I was working on got cancelled so I never got to finish and share it.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Emscripten documentation](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/Tutorial.html#generating-html) you can use SDL with C++ to get at the canvas when you generate Javascript. The SDL conversion is implemented in native canvas calls.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, SDL initialized with `SDL_SWSURFACE` will created a "2d" context rather than a "webgl"/"experimental-webgl" one.  Functionality can be seen in the sdl_rotozoom test or on GitHub: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/tests/sdl_rotozoom.c

Answer (score 1):

I've used dynamic binding throught [embind / `emscripten::val`](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#embind-val-guide)

Example (emscripten v3.0.0):

```cpp
#include <emscripten/val.h>

auto main() -> int {
  const auto document = emscripten::val::global("document");
  const auto canvas =
      document.call<emscripten::val, std::string>("querySelector", "canvas");

  auto ctx = canvas.call<emscripten::val, std::string>("getContext", "2d");

  const auto width = canvas["width"].as<int>();
  const auto height = canvas["height"].as<int>();

  ctx.call<void>("clearRect", 0, 0, width, height);

  // rect
  ctx.set("fillStyle", "white");
  ctx.call<void>("fillRect", 0, 0, width, height);

  // line
  ctx.set("strokeStyle", "black");
  ctx.call<void>("moveTo", 0, 0);
  ctx.call<void>("lineTo", width, height);
  ctx.call<void>("stroke");

  // text
  ctx.set("fillStyle", "black");
  ctx.set("font", "bold 48px serif");
  ctx.call<void, std::string>("fillText", "Hello World!", width / 2,
                              height / 2);

  return 0;
}
```

`emcc src/main.cpp -g -s ENVIRONMENT='web' -std=c++20 --bind -o build/main.js`

P.S.

btw same approach can be used to work with any Web API, if no static/predefined bindings exist in emscripten or you just don't want to use ones that exist. E.g. I wanted to stick to [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) Web API as close as possible, so SDL wasn't my choice.